# Kubernetes 1.16 logstash helm chat no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta2"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy the logstash helm on kubernetes cluster 1.16. but it giving below error message. How to update this Kubernetes API change for this helm chart?

```
helm install --name logstash stable/logstash -f values.yaml 
Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta2"
```

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/logstash

Thanks

Comment: what do you get if you issue `helm template <logstash_dir_path>` ? no errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes 1.16 [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/) the `apps/v1beta2` API version. You need to use `apps/v1` instead.

The *stable/logstash* chart already [has a commit](https://github.com/helm/charts/commit/0274cecf530f6191ea2ef667268debf3fa857dd2) that upgraded the API version. Make sure that you are using the `2.3.0` chart version and it should work. E.g:

```
helm repo update
helm install --name logstash stable/logstash --version=2.3.0 -f values.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

When these things happen, you can always use `kubectl exaplain` command to get the right version of the API.

Example:

```
$ kubectl explain statefulset
KIND:     StatefulSet
VERSION:  apps/v1

DESCRIPTION:
     StatefulSet represents a set of pods with consistent identities. Identities
     are defined as: - Network: A single stable DNS and hostname. - Storage: As
     many VolumeClaims as requested. The StatefulSet guarantees that a given
     network identity will always map to the same storage identity.

FIELDS:
   apiVersion   <string>
     APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an
     object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal
     value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/api-conventions.md#resources

   kind <string>
     Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this object
     represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client submits
     requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/api-conventions.md#types-kinds

   metadata     <Object>

   spec <Object>
     Spec defines the desired identities of pods in this set.

   status       <Object>
     Status is the current status of Pods in this StatefulSet. This data may be
     out of date by some window of time.
```

As you can see, under version, it states the API version the cluster supports, for that specific object.